# Django array to string

Tags: python, arrays, django, orm

I have data in database like array,

Table A

```
instant language
1       english
1       Indonesia
2       japan
2       korea
2       british
```

this is models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    instant = models.ForeignKey(Instant)
    language = models.ForeignKey(language)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.language)
```

I want to make it to be string like this:

```
instant language
1       english,Indonesia
2       japan,korea,british
```

Before I use Django ORM, I use PHP and mysql and just make query like this

```
select instant,array_to_string(array_agg(language), ',') as unit 
            from A 
            where A.id_language = b.id_language group by A.id_language");
```

how to query in ORM django?

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when creating question.

Comment: you can see i edit above. before i use php and mysql, and now i want to change use django

Comment: Have you create the Django model?

Comment: yes, I have. I already put in models in above

Answer (score 0):

You must use the get method from the model class. It will be something like this.

```
Class.objects.get(PK)
```

In your case:

```
object = A.objects.get(language=english)
```

in object you will have an object of type class A. After that you can retrieve the info and pass it to String or do whatever you want with it.

EDIT:

If you want to select all.

```
objects = A.objects.all()
```

In this case you will have an array of objects from your type and you can transform them in the way you want.

Is so easy to make queries in Django but if you are not careful they can be slow and when you have lots of info your app will be slow. There are tons of useful info about queries and how to make them here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/